# Cant see option of upload APK in my suspended android app

Tags: android, google-play

Android team rejected my application due to some security reason and asked me to upload new APK.I resolved issues but I can't see option of upload APK in developer console if I select my suspended app. is there way to resubmit my APK again?

Answer (score 1):

If your application is suspended, you cannot upload new apk or make changes to application. App will not be available to users to download either.

1. You can appeal against the suspension if you have enough evidence to support your claim. Once suspension is removed you can upload new apk in same app.
2. You need create completely new application to upload you apk ( name/title of new app cannot be similar to your existing app ).